# Cant get selected item id

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have simple form. It contains few texboxes and one dropdown list. And I cant get selected item id to save it into database.

This is controller method whitch displaing a form

```
public ActionResult DisplayForm()
        {
            ViewBag.State = new SelectList(conn.state, "STATE_Id", "STATE_Name");
            return View(new order_data());
        }
```

this is method whitch should save data into database

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MakeOrder(order_data data, state stateId)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                conn.order_data.Add(data);
                conn.SaveChanges();
                RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

This is my view

```
@model bookstore.order_data

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dane osobowe";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>DisplayForm</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("MakeOrder","Order"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>

     <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ORDA_Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ORDA_Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ORDA_Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ORDA_LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ORDA_LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ORDA_LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ORDA_Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ORDA_Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ORDA_Email)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ORDA_Phone)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ORDA_Phone)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ORDA_Phone)
        </div>


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ORDA_CityName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ORDA_CityName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ORDA_CityName)
        </div>


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.state)
        </div>
        @Html.DropDownList("State", "--wybierz województwo--")



        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ORDA_StreetName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ORDA_StreetName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ORDA_StreetName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ORDA_StreetNr)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ORDA_StreetNr)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ORDA_StreetNr)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ORDA_HomeNr)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ORDA_HomeNr)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ORDA_HomeNr)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ORDA_ZIP)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ORDA_ZIP)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ORDA_ZIP)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

and this is model whitch contains client data

```
namespace bookstore
{
    public partial class order_data
    {
        public order_data()
        {
            this.orders = new HashSet<orders>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int ORDA_ID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("state")]
        public Nullable<int> State_STATE_Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Miasto")]

        public string ORDA_CityName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Ulica")]
        public string ORDA_StreetName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Numer ulicy")]
        public string ORDA_StreetNr { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Numer domu")]
        public string ORDA_HomeNr { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Kod pocztowy")]
        public string ORDA_ZIP { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Email")]
        public string ORDA_Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Imię")]
        public string ORDA_Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Nazwisko")]
        public string ORDA_LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Telefon")]
        public string ORDA_Phone { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Województwo")]
        public virtual state state { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<orders> orders { get; set; }
    }

}
```

and this is model which contains dropdown list data

```
public partial class state
    {
        public state()
        {
            this.order_data = new HashSet<order_data>();
        }

        public int STATE_Id { get; set; }
        public string STATE_Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<order_data> order_data { get; set; }
    }
```

By the way, i need to pass a orderid into controller too and i dont know how, becouse id always equals 0

Please, help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't orderId (ORDA_ID) a KEY in your order_data table ? So it's being assigned when you insert a row into the table. So either I don't fully understand your question or you're not trying to pas orderId into the controller.

after you execute

```
conn.order_data.Add(data);
conn.SaveChanges();
```

you will be able to get your ORDA_ID by :

```
int orderId = data.ORDA_ID;
```

if this is what you need

Comment: Yes, orderId is primary key of table order_data. The problem is I cant add data into table, becouse primary key dont set

Comment: are you using DB-first or Code First approach? If the error says that ORDA_ID is not set and you're using DB first (usage of partial class would indicate such thing) then I would say you're missing Identity option set on your PK

Comment: i have no error. When I create a database i was set identity option on this column. When I debbug it ORD_Id = 0, always..and my ModelState is no valid. But I think is connected with state field.

Comment: if you're only extending your db model classes why are you adding [Key] and [ForeignKey] attributes? Maybe there's something I don't know but that doesnt look right to me. This is all defined in you edmx , so why putting it into partial class?

Comment: There is no diffrence. Becouse without [Key] parameter isnt work too. All model was generated automaticly becouse I've used ADO.NET Entity Data Model and later use Generate database from model option

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6634/discussion-between-lukaszb-and-torm)